# Why does push not work on this cookie array?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

This works fine:

```
$cookies.animals = []
$cookies.animals.push({cat: 'meow'})
console.log($cookies.animals) -> [Object]
```

But identical code inside a factory function doesn't work:

```
addAnimal: function(id, name, price){
    console.log($cookies.animals) //-> [object Object] 
    $cookies.animals.push({cat: 'meow'}) //-> TypeError: undefined is not a function
}
```

**So why am I getting a TypeError?**

If I do this

```
addAnimal: function(id, name, price){
    $cookies.animals = []
    console.log($cookies.animals) //-> [] 
    $cookies.animals.push({cat: 'meow'}) //-> works
}
```

It works (though of course it resets the array) so some something weird is happening to `$cookies.animals`.

If we look at my `console.log` inside the factory function:

We get this:

```
[object Object]
```

`Object` with a capital `O` is my cat, but that weird `object` is doing something evil I think. Where does it even come from?

Really don't know what's going on to be quite honest. Help please. All I'm trying to do is append to an array...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the [AngularJS $cookie documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies):

> Only a simple Object is exposed and by adding or removing properties to/from this object, new cookies are created/deleted at the end of current $eval. **The object's properties can only be strings.**

Your initial code works because you can, at any time, set any type of property on any object. Angular does not hold onto your non-string values, though, so your `animals` property is no longer set in the latter use context. You'll have to serialize and deserialize (probably via [JSON](http://json.org)) when writing and reading (respectively).

So you'll need to do something like this to initialize the cookie:

```
var animals = [];

animals.push('Furry Cat');

$cookies.animals = JSON.stringify(animals);
```

Later when reading, you'd need to do this:

```
var animal_cookie_value = $cookies.animals,
    animals = animal_cookie_value ? JSON.parse(animal_cookie_value) : [];
```

As for your added remark of:

> `Object` with a capital `O` is my cat, but that weird object is doing something evil I think. Where does it even come from?

When you see

```
object Object
```

in JavaScript you are seeing the output of the default `toString()` method on JavaScript objects. In other words, you used an object in context of a string, so JS cast it to string (which results in the value you're questioning).

FWIW, I develop a JavaScript cookie library which allows you to pass in any data and it handles the serialization for you. It is currently hosted on [Google code](https://code.google.com/p/cookies/), but I am working on moving it to [GitHub](https://github.com/JAAulde/cookies) and hope to add an AngularJS module for it someday.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on serializing and deserializing? Possibly with an example? Thanks

Comment: I've added a link to the page which lays out JSON serialization, and added minimal code examples.

Comment: @JJAAulde Cool...is this a work around though? Or is doing this fine and widely used? The only alternative is store in multiple cookies, but I don't want to fill up the client with a load of cookies!

Comment: I also eagerly await your module :)

Comment: This is a work around to the fact that cookies are, by definition, only strings. Data serialization is how we handle such situations, and JSON is quickly becoming THE way to serialize. See my final paragraph that I added to the answer to find out a little more about my background with it and to find a resource for learning a little more on cookies and JSON.